# Boxplot for a theoretical distribution in T

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, boxplot

I would like to be able to draw a boxplot for a given theoretical distribution. For example, let's say I want to draw a boxplot for the normal distribution. R has the method qnorm. So I can get the first, second, and third quartile like this:

```
quartiles <- qnorm((1:3) / 4)
```

the interquartile range can be obtained:

```
irq <- quartiles[3] - quartiles[1]
```

the whiskers can be obtained:

```
left.whisker <- quartiles[1] - irq * 1.5
right.whisker <- quartiles[3] + irq * 1.5
```

Now, how can I create a boxplot?

I know that I can use rnorm and then use the method bixplot but I would like to be able to draw the boxplot based on the theoretical distribution. It is useful for teaching so students don't have to worry about the number of values they have to simulate and also the output will not depend on the number of values simulated.

Thanks,
Nikola

Comment: You should do some searching on SO and rhelp.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `bxp` function can be used to create a boxplot based on supplied summary statistics (the `boxplot` function calls `bxp` to do its plotting).  So you just need to create the correct type of object and pass it to `bxp`:

```
q1 <- qnorm(0.25)
q2 <- qnorm(0.5)
q3 <- qnorm(0.75)

lower <- q1 - 1.5*(q3-q1)
upper <- q3 + 1.5*(q3-q1)

tmp.list <- list( stats=rbind(lower, q1, q2, q3, upper),
    out=numeric(0), group=numeric(0), names='')

bxp( tmp.list )
```

Comment: I would suggest using something like the 1st and 99th percentiles as the ends of the whiskers rather than the +-1.5IQR, the above is ok for symmetric distributions, but for skewed distributions the percentiles would probably be more meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

If this is used for a class, I think plotting the theoretical quantiles fails to convey the connection of the distribution to the real world, where variation is everywhere and standard normals are only observed asymptotically.

This is my attempt to show the relationship of a random variable to the theoretical quantiles.

Notice that I am sampling using `rnorm`, I also plot the data behind the `geom_boxplot` using the `geom_jitter` geom.  Changing the `alpha` settings will affect transparency.

```
install.packages("gridExtra"); install.packages("ggplot2")
library(gridExtra); library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(list(our_rand_var = rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)))

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = our_rand_var)) +
  geom_density(fill = "white") +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "Our Variable", y = our_rand_var)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.9, colour = "red", size = 2) +
  ylab("Standard Deviations") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 1, 
             main = "Standard Normal Distribution (~Z)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly random distribution:

```
set.seed(1)
d1 <- c(rbeta(5,1,1), runif(5))
boxplot(d1)
```

If you look at the code, with `graphics::boxplot.default` you'll see it calls a function `boxplot.stats` (in package `grDevices`), which you can call to give you the values required for a boxplot. This in turn calls 
`stats::fivenum` and the method, applied to vector `x` is:

```
x <- sort(x)
n4 <- floor((length(x) + 3) / 2) / 2
d <- c(1, n4, (length(x) + 1) / 2, length(x) + 1 - n4, length(x))
0.5 * (x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)])
```

Comment: I think you will find that `boxplot.stats` calls `fivenum`.